# C#: How do I create a WMP PositionChangeEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-media-player, wmp

I am relativly new to C# and also new in the Stackoverlow-community.

At the moment i am trying to create an audioplayer, which can loop an audiofile smoothly, by overlapping two playing instances of this file and fading between those.

I use the  WMPLib Windows Media Player. Until now I connected 2 WMPs with 2 Timers, which is not very precise and also buggy, when used with short Audiofiles.

While puzzling possible new solutions, i stumbled over the "PositionChangeEvent" from the WMP, which could be very useful for my Project. However i do not now how to use it.

For a timer i do it like this:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

(...)

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){//...}
```

but an Event build like this, doesnt work for:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();   
wplayer.PositionChange += new _WMPOCXEvents_PositionChangeEventHandler(wplayer_PositionChange);
```

the error is 
No overload for 'wplayer_PositionChange' matches delegate 'WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PositionChangeEventHandler

So, how do i create the correct event?

EDIT: Okay. I solved it by myself. apparently pressing tab in visual studio after typing the "wplayer.PositionChange +=" automaticly inserts the event handler, and pressing tab again, automaticly adds the new event.

Comment: Okay. I solved it by myself. apparently pressing tab in visual studio after typing the "wplayer.PositionChange +=" automaticly inserts the event handler, and pressing tab again, automaticly adds the new event.